# Fastai text classifier: batch prediction on unseen data

Tags: python, deep-learning, fast-ai

I have being working with fastai's text classifier (https://docs.fast.ai/text.html). I currently predict the sentiment (positive or negative) of unseen phrases as it follows:

```
def _unpack_prediction(self, text) -> Tuple[bool, float]:
    out = self._model.predict(text)
    return str(out[0]) == "positive", max(out[2][0].item(), out[2][1].item())

def example(self, messages: Sequence[str]):
    results = map(self._unpack_prediction, messages)
    for phrase, out in zip(messages, results):
        print(f"{phrase[:100]}...[{'pos' if out[0] else 'neg'}] - [{out[1]:.2f}]")
```

Given a list of phrases:

```
("I love this movie",
  "The actors are good, but this movie is definitely stupid",
  "There is no plot at all!!! Just special effects ")
```

The result is:

```
I love this movie...[pos] - [1.00]
The actors are good, but this movie is definitely stupid...[neg] - [0.96]
There is no plot at all!!! Just special effects ...[neg] - [0.95]
```

However, sequentially applying prediction on phrases is pretty slow.

Is there a way to apply batch prediction with fastai library without creating a test dataset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You most certainly can. Here is sample code to do that

```
test_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_test_csv_file)
learn.data.add_test(test_df[target_col_name])
prob_preds = learn.get_preds(ds_type=DatasetType.Test, ordered=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! For information, I was working with fastai 1.0.42 and I had to upgrade to the most recent version for this to work.

Comment: the `ordered` arg is undocumented, do you know what it does?

Comment: `learn.pred_batch(ds_type=DatasetType.Test)` will also give the results while maintaining the sequence of your iterable. Note I'm using FastAI version 1.0.61

Comment: can you update this answer for fastai 2.0? there is no learn.data anymore. Thanks